# Is it possible to work with temp variable in my batis "select"?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I have this right now:

```
<select id="associations-short-sql" resultMap="associationInfoForListMap">
    <![CDATA[
        select
               a.id as d,
               a.name as name,
               a.somenum as number
        from
               associations a
    ]]>
    <if test="id!= null">
        where a.id = #{id}
    </if>
</select>
```

But I need to add filter functionality. So if uri query has parameter name I want to add like conditional to the query. Both, id and name must be optional. So if params not set in url query, so query must be:

```
        select
               a.id as d,
               a.name as name
               a.somenum as number
        from
               associations a
```

If id is set query must be:

```
        select
               a.id as d,
               a.name as name
               a.somenum as number
        from
               associations a
        where a.id = #{id}
```

If name is set query must be

```
        select
               a.id as d,
               a.name as name
               a.somenum as number
        from
               associations a
        where a.name like '%#{name}%'
```

If name and number set query must be:

```
        select
               a.id as d,
               a.name as name
               a.somenum as number
        from
               associations a
        where a.name like '%#{name}%' and number like '%#{number}%'
```

But, when some params is set, I must to keep select-statement order correct (I mean `where` and `and` parts). This is rather easy examples, but it can be much more complex. For parameter `name` I should check if `number` is set, for parameter number I should check if `name` is set. For id, I should check if both name and number are set. What if I have 10 parameters %!@#!@? :)

Is it possible to store `where` condition in some temp variable? It will be much easier to keep correct order. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options to do that.

### Dynamic SQL

The first option is to use [dynamic sql](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) and suitable for many cases is built-in and doesn't require additional configuration:

```
<select id="associations-short-sql" resultMap="associationInfoForListMap">
  <![CDATA[
    select
           a.id as d,
           a.name as name,
           a.somenum as number
    from
           associations a
  ]]>
  <where>
    <if test="id != null">
      a.id = #{id}
    </if>
    <if test="id == null">
      <if test="name != null">
        AND a.name = #{name}
      </if>
      <if test="number != null">
        AND a.number = #{number}
      </if>
    </if>
  </where>
</select>
```

`<where>` element handles case when `where` clause is empty and doesn't insert it to result sql. It also trims extra AND at the beginning if you passed only `name` for example.

### Scripting

Another option is using [scripting](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#Pluggable_Scripting_Languages_For_Dynamic_SQL). Scripting in [velocity engine](http://mybatis.github.io/velocity-scripting/) is more expressive and powerful. Usually notation is more compact.
Your example might look like:

```
<select id="associations-short-sql" resultMap="associationInfoForListMap">
  <![CDATA[
    select
           a.id as d,
           a.name as name,
           a.somenum as number
    from
           associations a
  ]]>
  #where()
    #if($_parameter.id)
      a.id = @{id}
    #else
      #if($_parameter.name)
        AND a.name = @{name}
      #end
      #if($_parameter.number)
        AND a.number = @{number}
      #end
    #end
  #end
</select>
```

Additionally velocity allows you to have variables, loops etc.